# How to get data from childtable using foreignkey calling only parent table id?

Tags: node.js

How to get data from child table using foreign key calling only parent table id?

**temp table:**

```
Id   | tmp_name | tmp_desc
-------------------------------
1    | invoice | stream
2    | broad   | streaming
3    | voucher | conform
```

**images table:**

```
tmp_Id| id  | dest | img1 |img2 |Img3
-------------------------------------
 2    | 1   |insta |url   |url2 |url3
 2    | 2   |twit  |url1  |url2 |url 4
 2    | 3   |insta |url   |url2 |url3
 2    | 4   |twit  |url1  |url2 |url 4
```

`tmp_id` is the `foreign key`

I want the result like this:

```
{
   id: '2',
   tmp_name: 'invoice',
   tmp_desc: streaming,
   Images:    [
 { 
    tmp_Id:'2',
    id:'1',
    dest:'insta',
    img1:'url',
    img2:'url2',
    img3:'url3'
 },

  ]
}
```

I've got the error:

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError:
>   ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'tmp_id' in 'field list'

Comment: i tried all but the result is not came

Comment: is there  any idea for this one

Comment: StreamingTemplateId = req.params.id;
    return TemplateController.findById(StreamingTemplateId).then(function(streamingTemplate) {
        res.json(streamingTemplate);
        TemplateId=req.params.id;
      return StartBroadcasting.findById(TemplateId).then(function(templateImages){
            templateImages.tmp_id=req.params.tmp_id;
            templateImages.id=req.params.id;
            templateImages.type=req.params.type
            templateImages.img2=req.params.img2;
            templateImages.mg3=req.params.img3;
        });

Comment: this is my code for getting data but i am getting only temp table data only. http://localhost:3000/temp/start/mail/:id/:id.here first id represent the temp table id then 2nd id represent tempimages table id

Comment: in console i am getting output but in postman not.